# Responding to media button events: MediaSession vs. MediaButtonReceiver

Tags: android, media-buttons

As described on this documentation page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/legacy/media-buttons, the route a media button event takes depends on the Android version.
On API versions 21+, it is the media session handling the event, with some differences throughout later API versions in finding the correct media session instance.

There's also the MediaButtonReceiver (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver), a broadcast receiver that also helps in handling media button events. It is mentioned on several occasions that it is a helper for API versions prior to 21.
Most examples still include it in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I use a MediaBrowserServiceCompat to enable background audio playback, and only support Android API versions 21+. But I want to be able to disable the MediaBrowserServiceCompat if no support for background playback is requested. As the androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver looks for a service that can handle the media button event, it will annoyingly throw an exception if it can't find the disabled MediaBrowserServiceCompat.

So my question is: if I only support Android API versions 21+, has the MediaButtonReceiver a purpose at all, or should the media session take care of all media button event routing?

Comment: If you do not need to support pre-Android 5.0 devices, you can safely remove the MediaButtonReceiver from your manifest file. This will prevent the exception from being thrown when the receiver cannot find a service to handle the media button event.

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of the `MediaButtonReceiver` in the context of your application depends on the Android API versions you are targeting. Since you mentioned that you only support Android API versions 21 & above, the `MediaButtonReceiver` may not have a purpose for your specific use case.

In API versions 21 & above, media button events are typically handled by the media session. The media session is responsible for managing media playback & handling media button events. The media session can be set up & controlled using the `MediaSessionCompat` class from the Android Support Library.

The `MediaButtonReceiver` is primarily used as a helper for handling media button events on API versions prior to 21. It is designed to receive the `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` broadcast and deliver it to the appropriate media session or media session callback. By including the `MediaButtonReceiver` in your manifest file, you ensure that media button events are properly routed to your app on older Android versions.

Since you only support API versions 21 & above, the media session should be sufficient for handling media button events in your application. You can register a `MediaSessionCompat.Callback` to receive media button events & handle them accordingly.

Here's an example of how you can set up a media session & handle media button events:

```java
// Create a MediaSessionCompat instance
MediaSessionCompat mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(context, "YourMediaSessionTag");

// Set a MediaSessionCompat.Callback to handle media button events
mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
        // Handle media button events here
        KeyEvent event = mediaButtonIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event != null && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // Handle the media button press
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) {
                // Handle play/pause button
            } else if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT) {
                // Handle next button
            } else if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS) {
                // Handle previous button
            }
        }
        return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent);
    }
});

// Start the media session
mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

By implementing the `onMediaButtonEvent` method in the `MediaSessionCompat.Callback`, you can handle different media button events such as play/pause, next, & previous. This approach allows you to handle media button events directly within the media session without the need for the `MediaButtonReceiver`.